# How do I "slice" a content in an ini file

Tags: c, ini

try.ini File:

```
[teachers]
teacher1 = joseph
teacher2 = ryan

[students]
student1 = john
student2 = johnny

[class]
class1 = biology
class2 = chemistry
```

Source file:

```
char x[255];

file = fopen("try.ini", "r");
    
while (fgets(x, 255, file) != NULL) {

        if (strcmp(x, "[students]\n") == 0) {
            //This prints the title
            printf("%s", x);
        }
        else {
            //This is to test for else statement
            printf("test");
        }

}
```

I am trying to "slice" a content to get the title and its content below it. So for example, using strcmp, when the while statement founds a match, it will print its title and the content below it and ignore the rest of the content.

So the desired output will be:

```
 [students]
 student1 = john
 student2 = johnny
```

I was thinking that is it a feasible way and how to read the blank string in between the end of the top contents to the next title? For example:

```
  teacher2 = ryan
  <blank space>
  [students]
```

Comment: You can search for "c source parse .ini file"

Comment: I think I have seen through the parse .ini external libraries but I dont really understand how it works still. So I am trying to keep the program as simple as possible since I am doing a read of the ini file contents only, if it is possible to be done without using it. Although it will be useful to be able to use it as it will provide additional access like reading and writing ini files.

Comment: There may or may not be blank line before each section. Check instead if line starts with `[`, that indicates start of new section. `fgets` returns a buffer, remove the `\n` from end of line, trim it, it if length is zero then it is blank.

Answer (score 2):

> it will print its title and the content below it and ignore the rest of the content.

So, at the point where you know you are inside `[student]` section:

- read line
- check if the line contains `[<any text here>]`

  - if it does, exit or break
- check if the line is empty (or a comment starting with `#`)

  - ignore the line - repeat from step 1
- otherwise, output the line
- and repeat from step 1

So:

```
file = fopen("try.ini", "r");
while (fgets(x, 255, file) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(x, "[students]\n") == 0) {
            printf("%s", x);
            while (fgets(x, 255, file) != NULL) {
                if (x[0] == '[' &&
                        strlen(x) > 2 &&
                        x[strlen(x) - 1] == ']') {
                    break;
                }
                if (strcmp(x, "\n") == 0) { 
                    continue;
                }
                // TODO: maybe check some invalid input or comments
                printf("%s", x);
            }
   ....
```

Comment: I think I managed to understand the sliced contents based on the conditions, thank you! Though there are some conditions in between that might cause the slicing to not slice some contents that should be sliced.